# How to batch-convert MS Excel files page size from letter page size to legal page size using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 200 Excel files in one folder, with file extensions .xls, .xlsx, and .xlsm.
They were all typed in letter page size and I need to convert all of them to legal page size (landscape orientation). Is there a way to convert the page size for all files at once using VBA? So I don't have to open each file and change the page size one file at a time? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. There are many ways. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. In order to get better answers please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask . This will avoid much frustration.

Comment: this is what you're looking for https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup

Comment: @HackSlash I was looking at this article: https://superuser.com/questions/480225/how-to-batch-convert-ms-word-files-from-letter-page-size-to-a4  
I want to do something like the code in that article but I don't write VBA regularly so I am unable to modify the code for excel.
I only can create a macro that I can run one file at a time at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Youtube video that showed "How to edit multiple excel files in a folder automatically" --> Credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIIj5-267uI

My file name is zzz.xlsm

And was able to edit the code to change page size:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectorytoEditOriginal()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim q As Long

Filepath = "C:\TSS\"

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zzz.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
For q = 1 To Application.Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(q).Activate
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
Next q
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If this answered your question then click the green check mark on the left to show that this question is closed. This will give you points!